# Selenium server raise error : does not match current platform LINUX

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-server

I am using selenium 2.47.1. I downloaded the client and server and put then inside my project. When I started the server it logs this information:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar 
22:47:10.469 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
22:47:10.522 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02
22:47:10.522 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
22:47:10.547 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
22:47:10.660 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
22:47:10.660 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
22:47:10.661 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
22:47:10.661 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
22:47:10.766 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
22:47:10.766 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

I saw some logs and then I have my doubts about this line:

```
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
```

1. Why it has the internet explorer settings. I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I am using firefox and chrome.
2. Why it said that does not match the current platform LINUX.

With the server up and running, I ran my test project and it was the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'ok-ThinkPad-SL500', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at cucumber.features.StepDefinitions.navigateToHomePage(StepDefinitions.java:26)
    at ✽.Given I navigate to the home site(/home/ok/workspace/CucumberPOC/src/cucumber/features/UserRegistry.feature:6)
```

I downloaded the selenium server and client from [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Answer (score 3):

Its no problem at all.Please find explanation with an example and appropriate terminal statement which needs to be executed:
Requirement:needs to run a test or test suite on machine A and machine B.

ex: 
-I have machine A (IP : 192.168.233.155) and installed selenium-server-xyz-version.jar.

1.To launch Hub (terminal statement): 
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub

2.To run tests we need to register the node .

- To run test on local machine A :

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub
>   http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser
>   "browserName=firefox,version=10.0.12,platform=LINUX"

NOTE: you can change browser parameter as according to need of your test

- To run test or test suite on remote machine B; we need to register the node from the terminal of machine B:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub
>   http://192.168.233.155:4444/grid/register -browser
>   "browserName=firefox,version=10.0.12,platform=LINUX"

Why does it have Internet Explorer settings if I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I am using firefox and chrome?

Ans: 
Terminal output:

> INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>   registration is skipped:registration capabilities
>   Capabilities[{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true,
>   browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current
>   platform LINUX

the above lines are just an information that check is done against WINDOWS and existing platform is LINUX

even after mentioning the `-browser` parameters you can still observe the same. Thus all we need to bother about is providing `-browser "browserName=firefox,version=10.0.12,platform=LINUX"` in terminal statement.

*Multiple browser settings can be registered:*

ex:

> $java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub
>   http://192.168.233.155:4444/grid/register -browser
>   "browserName=firefox,version=10.0.12,platform=LINUX" -browser
>   "browserName=chrome,platform=MAC" -browser
>   "browserName=ABC,platform=XYZ" -browser ........

Finally [some platform reference]
    http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GridPlatforms